# arecord audio recording command

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am using the following arecord command to record the audio from a USB microphone. Although I set the arecord to record 10 seconds of audio, the start time and end time do not reflect this. Any suggestions as to why I am facing this issue?

[image]

As you can see above, it is taking 22 seconds. The recorded audio file however is 10 seconds. it is the audio of last 10 seconds out of the 22 seconds it seem to have recorded.

Any ideas why I am seeing this issue?

Comment: Try adding `-s 0` (which should be the default).

Comment: -s 0 options is not present in arecord command in raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the script to get a more verbose output:

```
arecord -v -D plughw:for -f dat test.wav -d 10
```

I suspect that arecord is trying to set up the file header before storing the audio. Wav files have file headers as explained [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).